# ajax form textStatus error

Tags: jquery, ajax

I'm using a jquery ajax for storing a data in the database. I call a service through a url and send data to it in the following way:

```
function sendmsg() {
    var msgf = document.contactfrm;
    if ((msgf.cnt_name.value.length < 3) ||
        (msgf.cnt_tel.value.length < 7) ||
        (msgf.cnt_text.value.length < 7) ||
        (msgf.captcha.value.length < 4)) {
        alert("لطفا کلیه فیلدها را پر کنید");
        return;
    } else {
        postcontact();
    }
}
requestRunning = false;
function postcontact() {
    if (requestRunning) return false;
    $('#diverrors').html('');
    $('#ajxsave').show();
    requestRunning = true;
    var psite = $('#contactform').attr("action");
    var postData = $('#contactform').serializeArray();
    $.ajax(
        {
            url: psite + '/user/savecontactuser',
            type: "POST",
            data: postData,
            xhrFields: {
                withCredentials: true,
                mozSystem: true
            },
            success: function (data, textStatus, jqXHR) {
                if (data.status == 'success') {
                    $('#tblcontact').hide();
                    $('#sptxt').html(data.alerts);
                    $('#divalerts').show();
                } else {
                    $('#diverrors').html(data.errors);
                    $('#imgcap').attr("src", psite + '/captcha?cnd=' + Math.floor((Math.random() * 1000000000) + 1000000));
                    $('#ajxsave').hide();
                }
            },
            error: function (jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
                alert(textStatus);
                $('#ajxsave').hide();
            },
            complete: function (data) {
                requestRunning = false;
                $('#ajxsave').hide();
            }
        });
    return false;
}
```

When i using the `alert(textStatus);` between error function alert showing `error`

I am not sure where I am going wrong. What can I do to fix this problem?

Comment: what is the error

Comment: Just showing error

Comment: The third parameter in the error-function callback is the actual error, you need to debug and see what does the "errorThrown"-object contain.

Comment: 1:SEC7118: XMLHttpRequest for http://ipanel.bazargarmi.com/user/savecontactuser required Cross Origin Resource Sharing (CORS). 

2:SEC7120: Origin http://www.bazargarmi.com not found in Access-Control-Allow-Origin header. 

3:SCRIPT7002: XMLHttpRequest: Network Error 0x80070005, Access is denied.

Comment: make sure your requested url must be same domain from where you are making ajax request.